# Gulp- Versioning for javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, gulp

I am doing bundling and minification for javascript files. I am doing this using gulp. Now I want that if I make any change in any of my file and hit gulp then it generate a new bundled and minified file with version number like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.test.com/bundle-1.0.0-min.js/"></script>
```

then

```
<script src="https://cdn.test.com/bundle-1.0.1-min.js/"></script>
```

I want to do this using gulp because I am already using gulp for other purposes. And one more thing if this is possible then is there any way that I don't specify version no in my html page every time I make a change and my html page get the latest version by its own somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. package.json contains all the npm dependencies of my project so what version should I read?

Comment: I made this an answer. I hope this will solve your questions. @Ask

Answer (score 1):

This is just a rename of the file in general. But this should really not be an automated task to increment the version number. Otherwise you will be quickly getting a version like `1.0.2092` what is not helpful. I would suggest to read the version out of the `package.json` and use it for the name of the file. Should be pretty easy, if you already worked with `gulp`.

If you don't want to use the global version (*`version` entry*) of your `package.json`, you could add an own entry for your bundle version. Or even use a different file than `package.json`. You could even use that as config for which files should be bundled, to have everything in one place:

```
{
  "bundle": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "files": [
        "path/to/file-one.js",
        "another/file.js",
        "..."
      ]
  }
}
```

Just a quick example:

```
var pkg = require("./package.json");
var gulp = require("gulp");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.src(pkg.bundle.files)
    .concat("bundle.js")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.extname = "-" . pkg.bundle.version + "-min" + path.extname;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
```

Note: instead of `rename` you can just set the `concat` name, but I like to split this. But just to be complete:

```
.concat("bundle-" + pkg.bundle.version + "-min.js")
```

---

About the second parts of your question, to replace things in your files:

This would be possible if you build your html pages too, and replace/inject the relevant path into it. You could use the version of the `package.json` again, to build it and replace. Or use tools like [`gulp-inject`](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject). That simple tool can add `js` and `css` files into your html templates. Just create an area where they should be placed in the html file, like: `<!-- inject:js --><!-- endinject -->`. Afterwards it is a simple `gulp` taks too:

```
var pkg = require("./package.json");
var gulp = require("gulp");
var inject = require("gulp-inject");

gulp.src("dev/index.html")
    .pipe(inject("bundle-" + pkg.bundle.version + "-min.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("prod/"));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how and when do package.json version updates?

Comment: _How:_ you open the file in an text editor of your choice. _When:_ whenever you did a reasonable change to that files. Ok, little joke. ;) As I tried to tell you in my answer, increment and changing of versions should only be done manually. So whenever you want to increment that version you do it by yourself and then run the gulp task to rebuild everything. @Ask

Comment: @elsbehr, that is the issue, I can't do it manually. I want everything automated due to some limitations.

Comment: so is there any gulp npm that do it automatically like 1.0, 1.1, 1.2. It doesn't matter that it will reach to 1.1000 because I'll have to make a change once in a blue moon but I can't do it manually

Comment: You can't increment a version in some file of your project? Why? If you can't do it manually, how should a script do it automatically? And even then, I would not suggest you a way to it by an automated task, because that is a really bad idea to do so. But please tell me more about your problem, why you can't do it manually and why do you even want to increment the version then? Maybe I have another idea for you. @Ask

Comment: Ok, so the issue is, I will create a gulp task and my code will be pushed to dev env and I don't have an access to that env. Also I am not the only  one who will make changes in the js files, others devs can also make changes and no body wants to open package.json file again and again. But I want versioning because we might have to use different versions on different environments.

Comment: Is there anyway I open the package.json file through gulp task and get the version number from there?

Comment: Yes, in my example you `get` the version number out of the `package.json` and use it to build. But if I understand you correct, you more likely to `set` the version there. And that is not a good idea.

After your description of the problem I still think this is a bad idea. Furthermore, I'm even more have the opinion you should really not do it. If you work with more developers you should go for a manually task. Or, if you work with a larger group of dev's, you should do some kind of staging your changes and then create a new version whenever you work is done. Thats how versioning works. @Ask